# Windows PIP - cannot run any commands. Invalid value for require-virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

If l attempt to run any pip command l get the following error:

```
Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

fale is not a valid value for require-virtualenv option, please specify a boolean value like yes/no, true/false or 1/0 instead.
```

Obviously, the value "fale" should be false. But I have no idea how to go about fixing this. I cannot uninstall pip and reinstall, l cannot do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In your question, can you include the command you used?

Comment: Hi @MarceloPaco It doesn't matter what command l use, even: 
```pip --version``` 
throws this error.

Comment: It's in one of your config files: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/topics/configuration/

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank yo so much. Yes l found the pip.ini file located here: 
%APPDATA%\pip\pip.ini

And within it: 
```[global]
require-virtualenv = fale
```